# Multiplatform app - localization

Tags: localization, multi-platform

I am developing C++ based multiplatform app. Core is in C++ and GUI layers are in native languages (Swift, Java, C# etc.). How should I handle localization for this? Should I use native solutions for platforms or create C++ based localization and pass strings via C binding API

```
const char * localized = CLocalize(const char * key)
```

I more or less just need GUI captions localization and I have the same localization for associated web-page. So generating different localization files seems to me like possible cause for errors. If I create my "own" system, I can use the same localization files that I am using on the web and that are tranlasted and maintained from our web based CMS. However, I can add exports to native (iOS, Android...) platforms.

(Key and localized strings, they both can be in Unicode)